# What is “what” in “what has been called“?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, clauses, descriptive-grammar, grammaticality

> Climate change is thus a prime example of what people have called a "social ecological system" with factors from different domains interacting on different spatial and temporal scales.

The above sentence is a part of an exercise in my English course. I was asked to change this sentence to passive voice.
So, I made it like this.. Climate change is thus a prime example of **what** **has been called** a "social ecological system"...

My question is what is the function of **what** (after a prime example of...) in this sentence? Is it a subject of noun clause or is it a pronoun of social ecological system? This is really confusing to me. Please help explain.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think it is a (dummy) relative pronoun.

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence. But what does it mean by a dummy relative pronoun?

Comment: Here’s a [link](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/relative-pronouns/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3Mv99_On7wIVVQ4rCh1NvAlCEAAYASAAEgKJd_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) to an article on relative pronouns. The “dummy” part may be redundant or perhaps inaccurate; it refers to words like “it” in “it is raining” - they are there just to keep the grammar happy, not to convey information.

Comment: _It's an example of [the type of phenomenon that] people have called a 'social ecological system'._

Comment: 'Testing and tracing has been fit for purpose' is an example of what have been called 'terminological inexactitudes'.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, "*what*" is a direct object.
To realize this, replace "*what*" with "*many things*', for example.

*"She has been called **many things**".*

"*Many things*" is also a direct object.

Some people might consider that "*what*" or "*many things*" in the sentences above are not direct objects but "predicative" constructions, especially if they consider that the verb "*call* ..." by itself doesn't provide enough meaning to the sentence (i.e., it is working as a "linking" or "copulative" verb).

But I don't think that is the case.

Semantically, "what" is an ***interrogative pronoun*.**

BTW, "*what*" is ***not*** a relative pronoun (or relativizer) in that sentence.

In order to be a relative pronoun, it should have been linking an inner sentence with the main sentence, in a "relative capacity".

For example, in the sentence:

*She was called what I suspected she would.*

"*what*" is a relative pronoun.